# Linux mail command not working like it used to

Tags: email, sendmail

I was using the following mail command in my crontab to which worked flawlessly until we re installed our mail server last Friday:

```
echo "Testing 123" | mail -s "ECS PostDate Processed" "layton.everson@gmail.com chrish@mycreditcompany.com" -- -r "noreply@mycreditcompany.com" -F "ServerCronJobs"
```

previously the "--" would rout the command line parameters to sendmail to send from a name and add a reply-to address.  Now it seems the -- is being ignored and all of the extra parameters are being treated as email addresses. so the email is going to:

```
from root <root@mycompany.com>
to me, chrish, -r, noreply, -F, ServerCronJobs
```

What is missing now?

Comment: What's the new and old version of the OS? You probably simply aren't running the same 'mail' command. Check `man mail` for the options.

Answer (score 2):

You probably got a different version of the "mail" command with the OS upgrade, and it doesn't have the same options.

Why not just use sendmail directly, instead? That's a standardized command that unix MTAs always emulate, and is designed well for scripted usage:

```
( 
  echo "Subject: ECS PostDate Processed"
  echo "To: example.1@gmail.com, example2@mycreditcompany.com"
  echo "Reply-To: noreply@example.com"
  echo "From: ServerCronJobs <root@mycompany.com>"
  echo
  echo "Testing 123"
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t
```

That can be done `( echo ; echo ; echo ) | sendmail` style instead to fit on one line.

Or, if it is all just `echo` instead of a command somewhere in that pipe, replace with a 'here document':

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t <<EOT
Subject: ECS PostDate Processed
To: example.1@gmail.com, example2@mycreditcompany.com 
Reply-To: noreply@example.com
From: ServerCronJobs <root@mycompany.com>

Testing 123

EOT
```